# Update Google Maps With Ajax on Dropdown change

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am using CodeIgniter with Gmap v3 as described here: http://www.in-the-attic.co.uk/2010/08/02/codeigniter-google-maps-library-using-google-maps-api-version-3/

I am trying to update Google Map using Ajax on Dropdown change. I see its being posted and a response comes back but the map goes "gray".

Any thoughts?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cats").change(function() {

    var v = $("#cats").val()

    });
    });


    function getcat(v){
    if(v!='') {
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "<?php echo base_url();?>home/ajaxmap/",
   data: "CID="+v,
   success: function(msg){
    document.getElementById('map').innerHTML = msg;

   }
 });
     }
   }
   </script>
```

Then in my controller:
I loop through and echo back
$this->gmap->addMarkerByAddress("address", description, etc);`

Comment: What is the response from the `home/ajaxmap/` Ajax call?

Comment: this is the response http://pastebin.com/QujbPZZU